# BluetoothDevice react on custom MAC address

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I have a Broadcast receiver, which is used, whenever a bluetooth device get disconnected. I set the mac device for a bluetooth device it should react via settings, but no matter what i do, it gets fired on every bluetooth device. Here is my Receiver:

```
public class Bluetooth_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        SharedPreferences bluetooth = context.getSharedPreferences("BluetoothDevice", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String deviceMac = bluetooth.getString("MAC", "22:22:97:1F:D6:0F");

        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(deviceMac);

        Toast.makeText(context, "" + String.valueOf(device), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (deviec.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            //Device found
        }
        else if (device.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            //Device is now connected
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            //Done searching
        }
        else if (device.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
            //Device is about to disconnect
        }
        else if (device.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            //Device has disconnected
            context.startService(new Intent(context, save_location_service.class));
        }
    }
```

}

I want my receiver to react only to specific device on disconnect(but still i need other method inside, for future functions). 
The toast gives me "null". The deviceMac string gives me a MAC correct address. I think i probably need to create new Bluetooth device, but i could not find a way to do this...Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, wow, after some days trying to find a solution, i found a simple way, but it works. I add if statement, that checks, if MAC is the same, i have saved in shared preferences.

```
        if(Objects.equals(String.valueOf(device), deviceMac)){
            else if (device.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, save_location_service.class));
            }
        }
```